# Applications do not close after exiting

Tags: applications, battery-life, application-autoupdate

I have lately noticed that, after last updates on my Samsung S3 mini (although I am not entirely sure which ones in particular), applications simply do not close after exiting them and keep running in the background. As workaround I have to manually end all the processes from Task Manager.

I have read a couple of similar questions recommending this or that other Application Manager to switch them down but I did not understand whether this is a standard behaviour for Android phones (that I somehow never noticed) or a bug introduced.

Also, why is that so? Exit an application means exiting an application, I see no point is closing them but still keeping them running behind the back: it obviously drains the battery strongly. Is it adjustable?

Comment: How do you know they are running and drain your battery? Android doesn't exit applications, unless there is not enough RAM for a new started one.

Comment: I checked the current status of the applications since at some point I noticed that my battery did no more properly charge. Manually closing all of them restores the natural behaviour and the battery returns to its standard performances.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you use the Greenify app. It really shuts down or hibernates an app after you exit it. It doesnt allow the selected process to secretly run in the background.
You can find the app [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify&hl=en).
The app works even better if the phone is rooted.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm reading the documentation though and it seems that it would in most cases even idle all the messages apps, providing you to get new notifications (as if they were truly inactive). Is it true or am I just misreading it?

Answer (score 0):

If your device is running on Android Lollipop 5.x than there is change in the behavior, all those apps that you can see on the multitasking screen aren't actually running in the background. This is a snapshot of recent apps only some of them are actually running in the background and this doesn't take much of battery. Android automatically closes the background apps whenever required.